# "For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames." on Imgur upload

Tags: bug, status-completed, imgur, framing

Ok first, there's that lugubrious use of the semicolon; not necessary.

Second, I didn't open a frame!  You did!  Alls I tried to do is upload a 5MB animated .gif file via Imgur.

[image: Semicolon in message]

Looking further into this, Imgur actually posts an error when you upload an animated .gif larger than 2MB.

[image: 2mb limit imgur]

Go figure!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the semicolon

Comment: Not sure the comma is necessary; the semicolon is fine however.

Comment: I thought .gifs were forbidden on imgur.  Or was that only for gravatar?

Comment: Well we should be declining all files that are 2mb or more earlier... I agree with that

Comment: I've [had this happen before](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=870822#870822) too (but I'm not sure what caused the underlying problem in my case), annoying stuff.

Comment: The semicolon should be a period and "Click OK ..." should be its own sentance.  The comma, however is correct.

Comment: I don't understand why people are concerned about a semicolon on an obscure error message that most people should never even see. Can the question focus on the underlying issue of SE not notifying us with the correct error response from Imgur... please?

Comment: The semicolon is *definitely* necessary. If it weren't there, that would be a run-on sentence. Can't have that!

Comment: As to the reason why this happens: The too-large upload causes an error page in the hidden upload iframe on *our* side (the image gets never sent to imgur), and that error page has the usual frame buster JavaScript.

Comment: Ok first, there's that lugubrious use of the 's' on 'Alls'; not necessary.

Comment: So it seems we know why this happens - are we planning to do something about it? I've been hitting it *a lot* over the last month but don't recall every seeing it before that.

Comment: @balpha any plans on changing that error message? People keep asking, and it's indeed quite a confusing message.

Comment: "Ok first, there's that lugubrious use of the semicolon **;** not necessary." And then there's your ironic misuse of the semicolon **:** "Oops!" :)