# Avatar image upload fails with frame-related error message

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, images

Today i tried changing my avatar image on stackoverflow and ended up with this error message, right after the upload was completed:

"For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames."

[image: Upload error]

The image was a valid JPG at 4.8 MB size.

Comment: sooo... what happens when you click OK?

Comment: relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133138/for-security-reasons-framing-is-not-allowed-click-ok-to-remove-the-frames-o

Comment: What size is the image file you try to upload?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Read the question... 4.8 MB (yes, that appears to be the problem)