# Adding a GIF in the profile shows error message

Tags: support, bug, profile-page, images

This is the message that appears to me as i upload an GIF image of grumpy cat smiling,

[image]

my thoughts are why is this happening? while this [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149052/nulluserexception) has a cute GIF of a gorilla walking in his profile, is this some kind of moderator power? if no, how can i/is there any steps to be made in order to add a GIF image in my profile?

Any guide would be highly appreciated

Thanks :)

**edit**
Im using chrome while browsing and uploading.
And as one of the commenter said it is working on his browser, is this also a cross browser issue?

Comment: Works just fine for me in Firefox 24.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII that one is a cool cat!

Comment: Why Downvote? please explain! tss.

Comment: One question: Why are you trying to upload a GIF of grumpy cat smiling?

Comment: @Emrakul i wanted to try the things i can see from others by that i can learn how a specific thing works. like for this instance that uploading GIF is not applicable to me, this thing make me wondered why others have GIF in their profile and i cannot upload it..

Comment: @Emrakul thus uploading GIF of grumpy cat smiling should be downvoted? or is the thought of the question that should be considered in upvoting and downvoting?

Comment: No, I was actually just curious. I haven't voted on the question. Don't know why this would be happening; try clearing your cache?

Comment: @Emrakul still the same already tried

Comment: How large is the GIF? This sounds like a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133138/for-security-reasons-framing-is-not-allowed-click-ok-to-remove-the-frames-o (also: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sHLgT.jpg)

Comment: I got a same problem and post it in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199294/error-on-changing-profile-picture .Its resolve next day automatically.Still I  don't know why its happen ?

Comment: @Shog9 i upload it in the profile tab not in the profile picture itself, it is 784kb only.

Comment: Mind posting the URL of the image that you're trying to upload?

Comment: @Shog9 http://designyoutrust.com/web/smiling-grumpy-cat/

Comment: Try: http://designyoutrust.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/tumblr_mkyfa5Acy51qkd0oho1_500.gif