# Adding large images to posts fails silently

Tags: bug, images, uploader

Attempting to add a large (15MB) image to a post fails with no error message.

When I try to drag and drop the image into the "Add a picture" dialog, it just stays uploading forever. In Chrome's network tools, I see that the post to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/upload/image has been redirected to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/upload/image.

When I try the standard browse to add, the entire window is redirected to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/upload/image.

Shouldn't I see an error message letting me know the image is too big?

For reference, here's [the image I was trying to add](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18277444/Review%20Suggested%20Edits%20%20%20Stack%20Overflow.png). (No idea why it was 15MB. I guess the Awesome Screenshot Chrome extension isn't so awesome.)

Comment: That image must be broken. No way it can legitimately be 15 MB

Comment: @probablyPekka It must be the browser extension I was using to create the screenshot.

Comment: Just tried adding [an image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18277444/Untitled-1.jpg) that was legitimately 17.9 MB (lots of random noise), and it had the same issue.

Comment: Try 8-bit PNG. No screen shot should be that large, and nobody is going to want to download it even if you *could* upload it.

Comment: An image size like this is beyond what you can reasonably expect a web service to accept, but agreed there should be an error message.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The point isn't that it should accept the image. It should tell me that it's too big. I honestly didn't realize the image was big until I started to submit a bug report and thought to see if other images would work.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I did get that error, once, but not when I used drag-and-drop. In Firefox, I saw the error briefly but was quickly redirected to the error page.

Comment: @Joshua oh I agree with that. I just read the first line in your post and it smelled wrong.

Answer (score 5):

That's by design on [imgur's side](https://imgur.com/faq#size):

> The maximum non-animated file size you can upload is 10MB. However, if the image is over 1MB then it will automatically be compressed or resized to 1MB, for better viewing on the net. The maximum animated file size (both GIF and PNG) is 2MB.

However, the fact we don't get such message and instead it fails silently is a bug on SE side that was already [reported here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133138/152859).

Until (if) it's fixed, whenever image upload fails here without proper reason, try uploading directly to http://imgur.com and see what happens.