# Uploading large images to Imgur is failing with a "500 (Internal Server Error)"

Tags: bug, status-completed, imgur, uploader

It appears that uploading large images (over ~4MB) will fail to upload and all you can see in the console is a 500 (Internal Server Error).

> GET https://meta.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/upload/image 500 (Internal Server Error)

This should instead display an appropriate error message instead of just hang there.  Perhaps warn about size limits of the images too.

I'm using Firefox and Chrome, latest

Comment: Feel free to use [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/2D8Ry39.png) if that helps you.

Comment: That's not quite the screenshot I was planning on showing but thanks anyway.  I could go directly to Imgur and upload there and link here but then it's not properly linked to SE.

Comment: You can take a screen shot and upload it to another hosting service, and provide a link for us.

Comment: @Flimzy: Yes I know that... but I'd rather not. This sort of problem doesn't _need_ a screenshot to explain it.  And if you haven't gotten the hint already, that last line was a bit of a tongue and cheek statement anyway.

Comment: Looks related to switching the image upload dialog, can you hard refresh and see if this is still happening?

Comment: @TimPost: No difference.

Comment: No repro here. What browser?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Firefox and Chrome, latest.

Comment: So it means something on your side is blocking something... hopefully Chris will find some hint in the logs. Can you do all of this with the Network tab of Chrome dev tools open to see if you can see something as well?

Comment: @JeffMercado I can't find any /upload/image exceptions in our logs, sorry. If you can send request dumps from your F12 tools, that'd be most helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: I've added the request data to the post from the failed upload attempts. I'm not sure if this is enough for you.

Comment: @JeffMercado How large is your image? Can you send us the image so we can try uploading it? You can email me at cky@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: Oh, it's a large image.  It's a screenshot from a game with some writing on it, that I intended to upload [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225045/what-do-the-orange-bat-head-icons-indicate-in-the-ar-challenges).  As is, it's a 4.4MB file.  I'll send it your way.

Comment: One of our devs just mentioned to me that, if he remembered correctly, the ASP.NET default file upload size limit is 4MB, and that we don't change from the default. So if it's 4.4MB, it might actually be above the limit. I should add some text to our image uploader stating this limit.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: That might have been it.  I reduced the file size down to 1.9MB.  I was able to upload that.  I think an error message there is in order.

Comment: @Jeff maybe change this report then to something like "Uploading images larger than 4 MB result in 500 internal error"? It obviously should show more friendly message.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208117/adding-large-images-to-posts-fails-silently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've implemented a handful of features that help with the image size checking:

1. A little message on the front page to advise users that there's actually a size limit:

   [image: max 4mb]
2. A more-eyecatching warning if you select a large image anyway (with the submit button disabled):

   [image: too large]
3. In cases where the user submits anyway, we now actually catch HTTP errors and report those back to the user. (The error message will just say Internal Error in this case, which isn't very helpful, but at least it won't look like it's perpetually-spinning.)

These features will be available in the next build (3525 on MSE/MSO, 2683 on other sites).