# What's the maximum image size one can upload?

Tags: bug, status-completed, images

What's the maximum image size one can upload? 2 or 4 MB?

The information seems inconsistent:

4 MB:

[image]

2 MB:

[image]

(also Mb is confused with MB, and mb is even more [wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix))

Comment: I still haven't tricked it into a 4MB one.

Comment: Bananas are larger than they appear.

Comment: huh, they fixed it. Anyway, very related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259294/uploading-large-images-to-imgur-is-failing-with-a-500-internal-server-error

Comment: @ShadowWizard Interesting, I still have the `4mb` on my side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be deployed as of build 3531 (on MSE/MSO) and 2687 (on other sites). Thanks to pacoverflow for doing the testing to determine the real limit!

(It's been changed to say 2MB everywhere, and not 2Mb or 2mb.)

Comment: However, ‘2MB’ is wrong; it shall read ‘2 MB’.

Comment: Okay, I'll check in the fix shortly.

Comment: @Loong The "2 MB" fix will be deployed as of build 3532 on MSE/MSO (and still 2687 on other sites).

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the maximum image size is 2 MB.  I tried to upload [this image](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/fable/images/1/19/Driftwood_8.png/revision/latest?cb=20110614193520) that is 2,303,164 bytes, and I got the following error:

[image]

A [different image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Hydrornis_irena_-_Sri_Phang_Nga.jpg) that is 1,883,430 bytes was successfully [uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAFwt.jpg).

Comment: That image you successfully uploaded is the sort where it does seem feasible to process the reflection in the eye to see the photographer.