# "framing is not allowed" error when uploading gif file

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, uploader

I was trying to upload a gif file (4MB) into a post. I get the following error:

> For security reasons, framing is not allowed. Click OK to remove the frames.

See this gif screenshot (click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40hPt.gif) if it doesn't play):

[image]

Why I am getting this error? Is the size of the file a reason?

Same story is here, on meta, when trying to upload same file.

Comment: I may be stating the obvious, but it appears you're browsing Ask Ubuntu inside a frame. Stack Exchange sites do not like to be framed.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I guess file uploader uses an `iframe` element (not sure), but the site is not in a frame... The response from the first request has a header that blocks iframes from other origins: `X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN`

Comment: Okay, so where does the top banner come from?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It's askubuntu site. Can't you see it?! And it's not an iframe...

Comment: Ah, okay, my bad, Ask Ubuntu does not use the same layout as the other sites. Not a frame, then, so the problem is not as easy as it first appeared to me. Are you behind a proxy of some sort?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Just connected to a router (via wireless) + modem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: The AskUbuntu site is 'special' in that it has some more UI to fit it into a wider series of Ubuntu.com sites.

Comment: That shadow... I like how it scales in proportion to the size of the dialog.  Because large dialogs are always much higher off the fake surface and nearer to the fake light source than small dialogs. #UIFail #NoHashtagsOnMeta

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow is now the meta site for **Stack Overflow** only. This bug hit you on Ask Ubuntu, so why are you asking here? It would make sense to ask on Meta Ask Ubuntu or on Meta Stack Exchange. Asking on Meta Stack Overflow seems odd.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about AskUbuntu and in now way suitable for MSO. Migrate it to Ubuntu's meta instead.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It does have to do with the size of the file. Imgur chokes on some files larger than 2MB, and the error it returns uses frames. Thus the error from the Stack Exchange code.

See: ["For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames." on Imgur upload](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133138/for-security-reasons-framing-is-not-allowed-click-ok-to-remove-the-frames-o)