# Can't upload big image

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, images

First of all, a screenshot storyboard:
[image: funny error]

[image: ?]

I tried uploading a 5MB image just as an experiment. The pro API shouldn't mess this up, right? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Doctor, what else do you need to know? I'm not the doctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5 mb is too large size. The maximum is near 2 mb.

As balpha said [in a comment on related report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133138/for-security-reasons-framing-is-not-allowed-click-ok-to-remove-the-frames-o#comment369428_133138):

> As to the reason why this happens: The too-large upload causes an error page in the hidden upload iframe on our side (the image gets never sent to imgur), and that error page has the usual frame buster JavaScript

Comment: @AnnaLear Is there a reason for this, or is 2MB just a magic number? I feel like big images can be helpful some times (especially on Photography, UX, etc.).