# Large image file upload is missing proper error handling

Tags: bug, images, editor

I was trying to upload [this](http://temp.twisterrob.net/share/so-scroll.gif) image when asking an [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) question, but I got the following message when pressing "Add picture" after selecting "From my computer" and browsing the file (you need to download the image first to repro):

> For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.

Then I clicked OK and presented with a question:

> You have started writing or editing a post.
>
> Are you sure you want to leave this page?

If I press "Stay on this page", the dialog continues the "Uploading..." animation.
If I press "Leave this page", I'm redirected to your [This is our fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/upload/image) error page.

I would expect you to say the file is too big or something more pleasant describing the problem, not redirect to a generic 503 page.

Comment: Regression or missed edge case with this, probably: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133138/

Comment: @senshin yep, I saw that, but that's been taken over by grammar nazis.